# Set one jsp field value to hidden field on load

Tags: jsp

I have 2 jsp fields duedate and oldduedate . duedate has value on load.I need to set the same value in a hidden field oldduedate...what should is use in hidden tag to get the value from duedate.

Comment: Can you show some code? What have you tried yet, where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value of fields in the JSP page is generated by the server, such as a servlet. Then you can set the value of the hidden field (oldduedate) to whatever value you set to the duedate field.